# ffmpeg Unknown input format: 'gdigrab'

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to record a specific window, so I tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30911430/10852052).

But it gave me this error: `Unknown input format: 'gdigrab'`

I'm using **ffmpeg version n4.4**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gdigrab` is specific to Windows. For linux, `x11grab` is the relevant device.

Run `ffmpeg -h demuxer=x11grab` to see its options.